# Current time but for yesterday

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to compare today's current revenue total to yesterdays revenue total where yesterday revenue total is only calculated for the same hours that were calculated for today.

Ex:-
Today: 12 am to 7 pm
Yesterday: 12 am to 7 pm

I want to make sure that yesterday data is always in sync with the current time of today.

Here's what I've tried for pulling yesterday data.

Table Columns:-
date : date ex. 2019-07-08
hour : hour ex. 2019-07-08 23:00:00 (in hour increments)
revenue : revenue

```
SELECT
sum(revenue) yesterday_revenue
from hour
where hour <= CURRENT_TIME - INTERVAL 24 hour and date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 day
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select sum(revenue) as yesterday_revenue
from hour
where hour <= curtime() 
      date = curdate() - interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below query to get the record as you want.

```
SELECT
sum(revenue) as yesterday_revenue
from hour
where hour <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) and date >= (curdate() - interval 1 day)
group by 1
```